# RailsAdmin how to limit listing records by conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have two models - `User` and `Article`, in which a user can have many `articles`.
In User there is a column `status`, which value is either 1 or 0.
My question is, in the user listing, how do I constraint the records by some conditions. For example such as `'SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1'?`

I have looked into Associations scoping, but don't think it's what I need.

For example in the picture below, author 'Kame Man' shouldn't appear in the listing.

[image]

Comment: I am using rails_admin, by default, it shows all records from the db, I don't know where to add the conditions.

Comment: [Fields visibility config](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#visibility-and-ordering), [per model config](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin#per-model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup `scopes` in your `User` model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(state: 1) }
  scope :inactive, -> { where(state: 0) }
end
```

Then configure the `RailsAdmin` to use the appropriate scope as default. In your case, `active` as follows:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model User do
    list do
      scopes [:active]
    end
  end
end
```

Refer to [RailsAdmin Wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The "Add Filter" drop down in the image you provided has columns you can add conditions to.